# What mean Preview in kubernetes version

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I'm planning to upgrade my AKS clusters to the latest supported version and when I run the command az aks get-upgrades i see the v1.24 is in preview . What mean preview ? could i upgrade my production clusters to a preview verison ?

```
az aks get-upgrades  --name myakscluster --resource-group AksCluster -o table 
 
Name     ResourceGroup    MasterVersion    Upgrades
-------  ---------------  ---------------  ---------------
default  AksCluster       1.23.8           1.24.0(preview)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It means it is a new Kubernetes version (1.24.0) that is now made available on AKS as a preview. I wouldn't use it in production because, well, it is a preview and some issues could be found.

Of course you could update your cluster as long as you take in account some things might be broken. If there is something in the 1.24.0 release that you really, really need to have in production you might take the risk but otherwise stay away from it and either use it on your test cluster or create a new cluster to try out the new features/changes.

The support for preview version might be limited, according to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/supported-kubernetes-versions?tabs=azure-cli#kubernetes-version-support-policy)

> AKS may also support preview versions, which are explicitly labeled and subject to [Preview terms and conditions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/preview-supplemental-terms/).

Answer (score 0):

Preview is a term that Microsoft uses to say that a service or product is in beta or in some sort of pre-release state. Note that the terms and conditions may change depending on the service being in preview.

In the case of the Kubernetes versions, the CNCF releases new versions of Kubernetes about 3 times/year. When Microsoft integrates a new version, it's first released as preview so customers can test it.

To answer your question, yes you can upgrade a cluster to a preview version. Should you do it on a production cluster? No unless you totally want that new feature that was shipped part of that K8s version.

The typical scenario is this one. You're currently running on version A. Version B comes out as a preview. You consult the list of changes published in the K8s documentation looking for breaking changes. Next, you create a test cluster with that preview version, deploy your app/system, and test for any issues. When that release reaches GA, you can upgrade to that version with confidence.

Read the [Kubernetes version support policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/supported-kubernetes-versions?tabs=azure-cli#kubernetes-version-support-policy).